# ActionMailer not sending mail in Rails 3.1.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, actionmailer

I'm getting error in ActionMailer when my worker is trying to send email

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    Connection refused - connect(2)

/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `initialize'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `open'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `tcp_socket'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:555:in `block in do_start'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:555:in `do_start'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:525:in `start'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:128:in `deliver!'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:1989:in `do_delivery'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:230:in `block in deliver'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:432:in `block in deliver_mail'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionmailer-3.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:430:in `deliver_mail'
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mail-2.3.0/lib/mail/message.rb:230:in `deliver'
/Users/bhushan/betterlabs_projects/companyplus_beta/cp_frontend/app/workers/set_crawling.rb:29:in `perform'
```

I have a file setup_mail.rb in initializers which has smtp settings

```
 ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 address: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 587,
 domain: 'betterlabs.net',  
 user_name: 'policemerepiche@gmail.com',
 password:
 authentication: 'plain',
 enable_starttls_auto: true
 }
```

and my mailer method

```
   def send_email(email)
begin
# attachments['result.csv'] = File.read(file)
 mail(to: "bhushanlodha@gmail.com", subject: "hey")
 puts "====Mail Sent===="
 rescue Exception=>e
 puts e.inspect
 end
end
```

development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Any insight on what could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method` set to `:smtp`?

Comment: I have config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp in development.rb

Comment: Can you connect to smtp.gmail.com:587 directly, e.g. via telnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the `:from` key that you have defined in the start of the `ActionMailer` class

Comment: I had written name in :from method instead of email. That helped!

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue, where my mailers would properly deliver emails if executing from the web process or in Rails console, but if they were queued up to deliver in a worker process, they would raise the Errno::ECONNREFUSED exception.

I too was using an initializer to set the configuration. Everything about it smelled like there were SMTP settings getting left out somehow, but only when being run by the worker process.

Eventually I added this to the mailer:

```
m = mail(to: "herpderp@example.com", subject: "Example")
puts m.to_yaml
return m
```

This revealed that the mail instance had an smtp settings object inside it (or referenced from within it, and included in the to_yaml) and this smtp settings object was without the smtp settings I was declaring in my initializer. Here's an excerpt:

```
settings:
  :address: localhost
  :port: 25
  :domain: localhost.localdomain
  :user_name: 
  :password: 
  :authentication: 
  :enable_starttls_auto: true
  :openssl_verify_mode: 
  :ssl: 
  :tls:
```

Obviously this was incorrect. Furthermore, printing Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings from the same declaration was printing the *correct settings*.

So to narrow down possibilities, I of course moved my settings declarations back to development.rb and the next time these settings printed on my worker's stdout, they were correct, and the email delivered as expected.

So I can't say that I understand entirely how/when configurations set in initializers are handled, because I don't have that much visibility into that depth of the Rails core modules, but I can say that somewhere in there, due to how a mail instance retrieves the smtp settings from the global configs, there's a difference between how/when they're declared in the initializer vs. the environment file.

Lesson learned for me. Don't move too far beyond the standard Rails configuration standards with an initializer class. Everything worked as expected once I moved the configuration back into development.rb. Perhaps someone else out there can help explain whats going on between environment rb files and the initializers.

Comment: The version of Rails I'm using, btw, is 3.2.11

Comment: So nice of you to share this!! I run into exactly the same case and started to nosebleed. With your help and after further investigating I found the reason: when loading your mailer settings from YML file, the keys are String, and action_mailer don't like that. This implementation works like a charm (in your environments file): `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/mailer.yml")[::Rails.env]` followed by `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings.symbolize_keys!`

Comment: Thank you for this!  I thought I was going crazy.  My initializer allows other delivery_method values and/or hashes (e.g. sendmail_settings or file_settings), so for each_pair of the loaded YML file I instead do `ActionMailer::Base.send("#{key}=", value.is_a?(Hash) ? value.symbolize_keys! : value )`

Comment: @Benj: Thank you for that comment!!  3 years later and that `symbolize_keys!` saved me hours of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

As Thilo above said; the obvious test is to determine if you can connect to Gmail's servers:

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 74.125.53.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ft1sm69312925igc.3
```

If you can connect, then your settings musn't be getting picked up during bootstrap.

I'd check to see where you are actually connecting to - go and add some puts statements into the smtp code (at or around line 546):

```
/Users/bhushan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb
```